# UIAnimate only happens once on button

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a button in my app that has a background image. When the button is pressed I want it to rotate 90 degrees. The code below is my IBAction. It works perfectly the first time, but every other time I press the button it doesn't rotate.

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: ({
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always set the transform to 90 degrees. If you want to rotate an additional 90 degrees each time you tap the button you need to update the existing transform.

```
sender.transform = sender.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
```